# Client-Server using socket: Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, client-server, eofexception

I am writing simple client-server program where server is listening for all incoming connections and accepts them. Once accepted, client sends data (integer) to server and server echoes back the integer to client. This part works fine.
Additionally client is sending data in succession (using while loop) on established connection, and thats where i hit a "java.io.EOFException" exception.

**Server**

listening on port : 3344

Received : 1 from client

listening on port : 3344

**client**

Enter Data to send: 
1

Server replied : 1

Enter Data to send: 
2

Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2626)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at Node.main(Node.java:28)

**Client Code**

```
    int serverPort = 3344;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", serverPort);

    ObjectOutputStream write = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream read = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    Integer writeData = new Integer(0);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Data to send: ");
        writeData = sc.nextInt();

        write.writeObject(writeData);
        write.flush();
        Integer obj = (Integer) read.readObject();
        if (obj.intValue() == -1) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Server replied : " + obj.toString());
        System.out.println();
    }

    write.close();
    read.close();

    clientSocket.close();
```

**Server Code**

```
        while (true) {
        System.out.println("listening on port : " + listenPort);
        try {
            clientSocket = listener.accept();

            write = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            read = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            int readInt = (Integer) read.readObject();

            System.out.println("Received : " + readInt + " from client");

            write.writeObject((Object) readInt);
            write.flush();

            //break;
        }
        finally {
            write.close();
            read.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            //listener.close();
        }
```

Comment: Is the server still alive and working at this point?  Perhaps it's no longer responding.

Comment: Yes. updated post with server console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client connects to the server **outside** the loop where your server closes client connection **inside** the loop.

Which means the client tries to write data to an output stream which belongs to an already closed connection.